# Adding element data with Array_push to JSON file

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to add data to existing JSON file

JSON:

```
{
   "s1":[
      {
         "bID":"q4a4xs",
         "bName":"Package1",
         "bStep":"slast"
      },
      {
         "bID":"q4a4xs",
         "bName":"Package2",
         "bStep":"s2"
      }
   ],
   "s2":[
      {
         "bID":"q4a4xs",
         "bName":"Package15",
         "bStep":"slast"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to create data for `s3`

**What I did?**

```
$newdata = ['bID' => 'O4bt2xs','bName' => 'Package91','bStep' => 's1'];

$newBox = 's3';


$encDexJSON = json_decode($json);
array_push($encDexJSON->{$newBox}->{$newdata}, $newdata);
```

**Print:**

```
  {
   "s1":[
      {
         "bID":"q4a4xs",
         "bName":"Package1",
         "bStep":"slast"
      },
      {
         "bID":"q4a4xs",
         "bName":"Package2",
         "bStep":"s2"
      }
   ],
   "s2":[
      {
         "bID":"q4a4xs",
         "bName":"Package15",
         "bStep":"slast"
      }
   ],
   "w3":{
      "Array":null
   }
}
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be fair, the code you provided along with the given data wouldn't even give that result. However, it's obvious that you are doing a great number of things wrong here.

For starter's you're trying to call an array on object property, which makes no sense `$encDexJSON->{$newBox}->{$newdata}`. That literally translates to `$encDexJSON->s3->['bID' => 'O4bt2xs','bName' => 'Package91','bStep' => 's1']` which obviously makes no sense at all.

Furthermore, `array_push` does not do what you want here. `array_push` is for arrays. What you want to do is simply assign a value to a specific object property. So just do so.

```
$encDexJSON->$newBox = [$newdata];
```

Now if you wanted to simply push new objects into that array...

```
$encDexJSON->$newBox[] = $newdata; // this pushes value onto end of array
```

The `array_push` equivalent would be...

```
$encDexJSON->$newBox = [];
array_push($encDexJSON->$newBox, $newdata); // same result as above
```

The use of `array_push` tends to get in the way. It's usually cleaner just to stick to the syntax above.